# How to bind data to mat-table dataSource using angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I have a material data table that i am trying to set dataSource dynamically but it throws error `dataSource` undefined, I am new to angular2 please help me to understand if below code has some issue.

stream.component.html

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
   <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ticketNum">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ticket Number </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ticketNum}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

stream.component.ts

```
import {
    Component,
    OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    StreamService
} from '../stream.service';
import {
    MatTableDataSource
} from '@angular/material';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-stream',
    templateUrl: './stream.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./stream.component.css']
})
export class StreamComponent implements OnInit {
    displayedColumns = ['ticketNum', "assetID", "severity", "riskIndex", "riskValue", "ticketOpened", "lastModifiedDate", "eventType"];
    dataSource: MatTableDataSource < Element[] > ;
    socket = io();

    constructor(private streamService: StreamService) {};

    ngOnInit() {
        this.streamService.getAllStream().subscribe(stream => {
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(stream);
        });
        this.socket.on('newMessage', function(event) {
            console.log('Datasource', event);
            this.dataSource.MatTableDataSource.filteredData.push(event);
        });
    }
}


export interface Element {
    ticketNum: number;
    ticketOpened: number;
    eventType: string;
    riskIndex: string;
    riskValue: number;
    severity: string;
    lastModifiedDate: number;
    assetID: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `this.socket.on('newMessage'` event is fired before   `this.streamService.getAllStream()` resolves, so have to wait until the dataSource is instantiated :

```
  this.streamService.getAllStream().subscribe(stream => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(stream);
        this.socket.on('newMessage', (event) => {  // <-- here
          console.log('Datasource', event);
           this.dataSource.data.push(event);
           this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data]
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: ok i tried that and `this.dataSource.filteredData` is printing outside socket but when i do `this.dataSource.filteredData.push(event) inside socket function its throwing error filteredData is not defined, Any idea ?

Comment: Sorry. see the update, use arrow function `=>` instead of `function`

Comment: ok making progress thanks for helping here i see new event is added to filteredData but binding is still not happening to the view it should update the view

Comment: see the update , use `data` instead of `filteredData` @hussain

Comment: sorry to keep asking questions, its same pushing data to array but binding is not happening for some reason. added more html

Comment: that's weird, add this : `this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data]` . see the update

Comment: we changed the reference of  `dataSource.data`  using this `this.dataSource.data = [...this.dataSource.data]` so Angular material knows  that data has changed. using `dataSource.data.push(...)` won't change the reference of `dataSource.data`.